# View bulk errors

Tags: 7, views

I create a rules component with 2 parameters to grant userpoints to user. I create a view and add bulk operation then I add my view on dashboard. All work great, but after bulk operation is complete I get errors:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: operation in views_bulk_operations_form_submit() (line 712 of C:\Sites\a\sites\all\modules\views_bulk_operations\views_bulk_operations.module).
> Notice: Undefined index: operation in views_bulk_operations_form_submit() (line 713 of C:\Sites\a\sites\all\modules\views_bulk_operations\views_bulk_operations.module).
> Notice: Undefined index: list callback in views_bulk_operations_get_operation() (line 229 of C:\Sites\a\sites\all\modules\views_bulk_operations\views_bulk_operations.module).
> ```

I tried use dev version of bulk module, but it also get errors. What should I do for fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution.

I created a panel and add my view block with bulk on it instead dashboard. and all work fine, without error. I hope somebody will find it useful.